# Need to sync data from one database in azure to another database where both databases have different location and different server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to sync two databases in azure paas having different location and different server.

When I try to create a sync group I'm not able to see the database in other regions.

Sync two databases in different location using azure portal.

Comment: Are they in the same Active Directory Tenant, if not then you can't do it directly through the Azure Portal but I believe it can be done using powershell, I didn't put this as an answer because I have exactly this situation and haven't gotten it to work yet!

Comment: Hi Adithya,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, please see [FAQ about SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data#faq-about-sql-data-sync):

**What regions support Data Sync**

SQL Data Sync is available in all regions.

Data Sync support you sync two databases in azure paas having different location and different server.

Did you followed this document: [Tutorial: Set up SQL Data Sync between Azure SQL Database and SQL Server on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) ?

For example I have two SQL database in different Azure SQL Server and region.

**Server 1:**

[image]

**Server 2:**

[image]

**Set 'Mydatabase' database in Server 1 as Hub database, add the 'dbleon' database in Server 2 as member database**:
 [image]

Every thing works ok.

Hope this helps.